# SSD Won't Initialze

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd

I bought a bare bones computer with 1TB HDD and 250GB SSD in it. I would like to install windows on the SSD and leave the HDD for files. When I installed windows it asked me what disk I would like install Windows on to, but it only listed the HDD. I installed Windows to there and thought I would migrate to the SSD afterwards. When I open up disk management it shows the SSD and asks if I would like to initialize it. I select yes and try to initialize it as GPT but it keeps giving me an error "The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error." Am I doing something wrong?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Update:

Windows 8.1 via USB installation media. No CD-ROM drive on board.

Motherboard
[image: Motherboard]

Disk Management/Error
[image: Disk Management/ Error]
SSD
[image: SSD]
BIOS
[image: BIOS]
SATA Connections
[image]

Second Update:

I contacted Mushkin technical support regarding the issue and they are shipping me a new one under warranty. Will see how the new install goes.

Comment: Try Change sata ports for ssd on motherboard and enable ahci in bios for SSD. This is the 1st step to diagnosing. by no means is it a solution.

Comment: We need more info. windows version. motherboard, ssd model, bios screenshot of sata connections. Screen shot of error. Screenshot disk management

Comment: Also, once you installed windows on HDD, that's it. It stays. There is a way to move to ssd, but thats tricky and can impact performace as OS orginally optimize for HDD. Thus don't bother setting up ur current installation fully

Comment: If I wipe everything clean can I reinstall to SSD?

Comment: There may be a driver related problem with ur SSD. Tell me info pls. No I do not know as of this moment if a reinstall will work. I guess there is a 5% chance it will work. haha or 0.5%. U need to give me info Mr Lars

Comment: If you are installing windows using a old DVD u will need to use updated ACHI drivers source: http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/247831-unable-get-fresh-install-windows-7-ssd-6.html

Comment: Do you want me to upload screen shots to Google Drive or Dropbox. Won't let me attach images without reputation of 10.

Comment: now it should work

Comment: I would try installing/updating/reinstalling the SSD driver first. Then If that doesn't work I would look into trying to reformat the ssd using a boot cd (which u'll have to find).

Comment: http://www.poweredbymushkin.com/support/ssd-firmware-updates